# Error: metric file not found

Tags: beamer, fonts, miktex

I am in one of those annoying situations in which I try to compile a file that I compiled several times in the past (without problems), but which gives me an error message now.

Under MiKTeX, if I compile this file:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item P
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I get the error message:

`! Font OT1/mathkerncmss/m/sl/10.95=mathkerncmssi10 at 10.95pt not loadable: Met
ric (TFM) file not found.`

Any idea about how to get around this problem?

Comment: Good evening, peraphs is it missed the fontenc (accents) packages? Have you tried to put it? Now I have used Papeeria and your code works correctly.

Comment: What I posted was a MWE. The original file uses the `fontenc` package and I have the same problem with it.

Comment: Yes, I want only help you. I use MikTeX too: today there were many updates. Probably all this may be due to the lack of update or other reasons related to your distribution.

Comment: I can compile your example without any errors or warnings. But I think @Sebastiano brings a good point: there were been a lot of updates in recently. Are you sure your distribution is up-to-date?

Comment: There was https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/162 a few days ago. But that issue was resolved. With my fully updated MikTeX I can run your MWE without any error and the output appears to be as expected.

Comment: @Vincent That solved my problem. Thank you I updated my distribution only three days ago and so it did not cross my mind that the problem was there.

Comment: @Vincent Thank you to have appreciated my thought. :-) +1 to your comment.